# vuex $store is not defined on cypress component testing

Tags: vue-component, cypress, vuetify.js, vuex, cypress-component-testing

Currently I am trying to do component testing with vue and using vuex as state management

and when run test case on mount the component I got the error stating cannot read properties of undefined like in the screenshot.

It seems that cypress is not aware of `$store`  that I used in vue component so do you know how I can fix that or is there anything I have to include in the configuration?

[code snippet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRp4K.png)

code snippet:

```
<v-data-table
  :header-props="{
    'sort-icon': 'mdi-swap-vertical',
  }"
  checkbox-color="primary"
  class="text1--text"
  :headers="$store.state.split.isOn ? splitHeaders : headers"
  :items="items"
  item-key="global_id"
  v-model="selectedRows"
  show-select
  :page="meta.current_page"
  :server-items-length="meta.total"
  :options.sync="options"
   @click:row="editTier"
></v-data-table>
```

**cypress/support/component.ts**

```
import './commands'

import { mount } from 'cypress/vue2'

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      mount: typeof mount
    }
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', mount)
```

**TierManagementDataTable.cy.ts**

```
import TierManagementDataTable from './TierManagementDataTable.vue'

describe('<TierManagementDataTable />', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    // see: https://on.cypress.io/mounting-vue
    cy.mount(TierManagementDataTable)
  })
})
```

[cypress error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9TMQ.png)

I tried to avoid using `$store` and switched to use `mapState` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/examples#Vue-2-1) say you need to enhance the `cy.mount()` command to include Vuex store.

In general, any plugins used in the app's startup code should be replicated in the test's `component.ts`.

**cypress/support/component.ts**

```js
import { mount } from 'cypress/vue2'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { getStore } from '../../src/plugins/store'

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, options = {}) => {
  // Setup options object
  options.extensions = options.extensions || {}
  options.extensions.plugins = options.extensions.plugins || []

  // Use store passed in from options, or initialize a new one
  options.store = options.store || getStore()

  // Add Vuex plugin
  options.extensions.plugins.push(Vuex)

  return mount(component, options)
})
```

Comment: How do I implement it with Nuxt 2 which I init store directly form store folder